# What is the story behind Lady Melisandre?

Tags: character, game-of-thrones

We have seen Lady Melisandre in season 2 of *Game of Thrones* with Stannis Baratheon, but who is she? How did she meet Stannis?

Comment: What real power? She made shadow, she melted ice, she shows visions in fire.

Comment: Why didnot with her power she helped stannis win the Winterfell,Even after loosing her daughter.

Comment: This doesn't happen in book and we don't know why she run away because it happens in last episode. But she have real power or her lord of light give her chance to use it. Maybe she have limits to use lord o flight's power.

Comment: tnks bro for explanation.

Comment: Actually Stannis asked to remove snow and that's what happened. he never asks for win as he don't want it to be her win instead of his win.

Comment: ok tnks for explanation bro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This wasn't explained in the show (apart from the fact that she has been a slave), the information we have comes from the books.

From [GoT Wiki](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Melisandre):

> In the A Song of Ice and Fire novels, Melisandre is a priestess of the
>   red god, R'hllor, the Lord of Light, whose worship involves the
>   idolization of fire and light. R'hllor is a popular deity in several
>   of the Free Cities (particularly Lys, Myr, and Volantis) but is almost
>   unheard of in Westeros. Although the series has altered some of
>   Melisandre's actions, van Houten's portrayal is overall consistent
>   with Melisandre as described in the books.
>
> Very little has been revealed about Melisandre's earlier life, other
>   than that she is originally from the city of Asshai in the distant
>   east. Melisandre recalls that as a small child, she was a slave named
>   "Melony". At the slave auction block, she was known as "Lot Seven".
>   She was sold at a young age to the temple of the Lord of Light in
>   Asshai, eventually rising to become a priestess, and thus has spent
>   most of her life in the service of the religion.
>
> Some years ago she crossed the Narrow Sea and came to the court of
>   Lord Stannis Baratheon on the island stronghold of Dragonstone, to
>   preach her faith. Stannis and the majority of his household have now
>   converted to her religion, and she has become a close adviser to
>   Stannis himself.

From [the books wiki](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Melisandre):

> Melisandre came to Dragonstone because she believed Stannis Baratheon
>   is Azor Ahai reborn and destined to defeat the Great Other the
>   antithesis of her god. (...) Melisandre proclaims Stannis Azor Ahai
>   reborn and has him pull a burning sword from the idols, declaring it
>   to be the legendary Lightbringer.

Comment: I'm not sure about *"Melisandre came to Dragonstone because she believed Stannis Baratheon is Azor Ahai reborn"* - I thought she was *sent* as an envoy, like how Thoros was sent to King's Landing - then she developed her theory after meeting Stannis (and then swayed him with her tricks)? I also remember one of them saying Stannis *sent for* her... which doesn't quite fit, either... would be great to see some direct show/book quotes